# PC4200 Memory in Dell Precision T3400?

Tags: memory, dell-precision

Is there any way to get PC4200 (ECC) memory to work in a Dell Precision T3400?  The company purchased this machine a few months ago for us for dev work, but spec'ed it with 2GB of RAM.  That doesn't work so well for VMs (or just Java IDE+app servers+DB, really).

I have some PC4200 RAM, but it doesn't want to boot with it installed.  Is there a workaround?  Or are we merely hopeless? ;)

Answer (score 1):

A good way to check your machine compatibilities for memory is with the Crucial tool
[CrucialScan.exe](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/index.aspx)

It will identify all upgrades you can do and give you direct purchase links if you wish to use them.

- Use working memories to boot the system,
- Scan with the tool (while connected to the Internet)
- Get the compatible memory list and check your PC-4200 against that

Answer (score 0):

http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Precision%20Workstation%20T3400&pl=Precision%20WorkStation&cat=RAM#

Well it sounds like your machine does support ECC ram, but I don't know if it supports that lower speed. That ram may be too slow to work properly with the computer. DDR2 PC2-5300,DDR2 PC2-6400,DDR2 PC2-8500 are the stated supported speeds.

Is the ram that is currently in the computer ECC or non-ECC? If it is non-ecc, it might not like mixed ram.

Comment: It is ECC, but so are the PC4200 sticks. :)  Sadly, I suspect that you are right about them being too slow.

Comment: What speed is the Ram currently in the machine?